# Some Magento cron jobs not running after moving to another server

Tags: php, magento, cron

After moving a Magento website to another server, not all of our cron jobs are running.

We have the Cron (scheduled tasks) setup as follows (System > Configuration > Advanced > System)

```
Generate Schedules Every: 15
Schedule Ahead for: 20
Missed if Not Run Within: 15
History Cleanup Every: 10
Success History Lifetime: 60
Failure History Lifetime: 600
```

And we have the following jobs setup

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <erp_update_stock>
            <schedule><cron_expr>00 * * * 1-5</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>erp/observer::updateStock</model></run>
        </erp_update_stock>
        <erp_orders_shipped>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>erp/observer::updateShippedOrders</model></run>
        </erp_orders_shipped>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

We've then recompiled, cleared the Magento cache and opened the cron.php page.

The **updateShippedOrders** job is running as expected, but the **updateStock** never seems to run or appear in the cron_schedule table.

We've even updated the **updateStock** schedule to run every 15 minutes without any luck.

```
<erp_update_stock>
    <schedule><cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>erp/observer::updateStock</model></run>
</erp_update_stock>
```

Comment: Stick in AOE Scheduler - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html, it's great for helping debug cron jobs and working out what's going on with all cron tasks.